# RAD 8.5.5 Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, websphere, rad

Am using RAD 8.5.5.3, with WAS 8.5.5.12 and optional installed SDK 8.
WAS is running with java 1.8, but in RAD am unable to select java compiler and project facet as 1.8, the drop down it self has till 1.7.

when i tried to modify org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml 
 to 1.8 
Am able to see 1.8 in project facets but it is throwing below error

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Under preferences go to the Build Path > JRE. Then add the jre 8 path to your RAD.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get you... you mean window > preferences > Java > Installed JRES...?

Comment: Yes.  If you haven't configured java 8 as an installed JRE, you should do so using what you posted.  Then you should be able to configure the compiler and project facet to Java 8.

Comment: No luck... Added in Installed JREs still.. project facets not displaying 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to RAD version is not compatible with java 8. We need to have higher version of RAD so that we will get default SDK 8 under IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/sdk/<setupsdk1.8 version>